# Normal Map Baking Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, normal-map

I got a problem about normal map baking which is annoying.
When i try to bake normal map from high poly to low poly baking ends so bad.
To inform you about what i did for resolve this problem.

These steps that i tried;

- objects are mirrored for using uv space efficiently.
- auto smoothed low poly objects, then i marked sharp edge to which
  sharp angles(30 degree).then i marked seam them.
- tried cage object with duplicated low poly object with displacement
  modifier (0.025 strength)
- tried 8 bit and 32bit float image.

these are steps that i tried to bake appropriately but none of these didnt solve this problem.

If there is someone who got enough knowledge about normal map baking i would so appreciate.
And if anyone show up i will share my model files to check my model because i will go crazy about these normal map baking problems. :/
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of blender to use?, if you use cycles, it is difficult to control if you do not have minimal experience with Cycles nodes. you could put the image of the normal map to see the defects and have a better idea that solves your problem

Comment: i use 2.80.74 build. actually i have been following a tutorial. i followed every step carefully but strangely i got a strangely problem while instructor doesnt have any.

Comment: i had no choice other than cycles. Eevee does not have baking option.

Comment: if the gun is equal to the tutorial I recognize the tutorial, mm I do not think I can help you, I avoid 2.8 is full of problems today and I prefer the 2.79 because I know it very well, if it does not do anything extraordinary 2.8 with the normal map, I suggest I did it in 2.79, while you practice or solve the problem in 2.8, I'm honest, I do not intend to use it until I see a stable version and a less ugly and unpleasant interface

Comment: thanks mate, then i will try to same baking process on 2.79. maybe problem is 2.8.

Comment: Ask my friends, they say that this works for 2.79 and 2.8, which helps you [High poly to Low poly workflow : Blender Cycles Baking 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOYRCI-dtjU)

Comment: I think this is easier to understand for 2.8 [Blender 2.8 Quickie How To Bake Normal Maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h24akA8K-40) I can compile 2.8 to test, I'll do it weekend and I warned you that I could do ok